# How do I change the width of a div when it is viewed on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ipad, html, width

What I want to do is make the div of the opt-in box at the top on the posts and pages stretch across. I wanted to do it using the width:100% attribute in CSS, but it was only stretching across partway.

So I manually set the width to the # of pixels that would make it 100%. But the problem with that is that it is causing display issues on iPhone/iPad.

Is there a way to have  the width of a div change on iPhone/iPad to fit to scale? How could I do this?

Thank you!

Liz

code---

```
.page-opt {
margin-left:-314px;
width:1583px;
clear: both;
margin-bottom:-20px;
padding-bottom:-20px;
position: relative;
}

/* Non-Retina */
@media screen and (-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
margin:0;
}

/* Retina */
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3/2),
only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {
margin:0;
}

/* iPhone Portrait */
@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) and (orientation:portrait) {
margin:0;
} 

/* iPhone Landscape */
@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) and (orientation:landscape) {
margin:0;
}

/* iPad Portrait */
@media screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (orientation:portrait) {
margin:0;
}

/* iPad Landscape */
@media screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (orientation:landscape) {
margin:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the section regarding viewport:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html

You can make use of "device-width".

Comment: did you add <meta name = "viewport" content = "width = device-width"> to your html file?

Comment: I did add that before - let me try it again and test. :)

Comment: OK just did it... didn't work.

Is it possible to set initial scaling in the actual CSS of that div?

Comment: You need that viewport in html as above then in your div use device-width to specify size

Comment: Thank you for your help so far, savner! When you say use device-width, do you mean that I should indicate the width of the div under each device I put on that list? So it should say, width=100% (for example)?

Comment: It should say width=device-width

Comment: so it should eliminate having a specific one for each device

Comment: Oh! Okay I see your point.

So I implemented your adjustment (thank you) --- I'm noticing white space when viewing this on iPhone ---- it's weird because the background color of everything up top is set to that purple. 

If you have an iPhone, do you see the reason why this would be happening?

Comment: I just noticed that the page width is set... Should I be adjusting it?

.full_width .page { width: 95.6em; margin: 0 auto; padding-right: 2.2em; padding-left: 2.2em; }

Comment: Try adding <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0"> to your html page.

Comment: OK! Now it is viewable in iPad. Still wonky on iPhone. Is there one little piece of code I can add to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
#youroptinid { max-width: 1600px; width: 100%; clear: both; }
```

if that doesn't work please post your html and css code so we can help you. Without code we can only speculate.